# Renaming root element and eliminating null values using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

I had to transform following xml input,

```
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
        <Standard>
            <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
            <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
            <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
            <DraftProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>1500163</ProductID>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </DraftProducts>
            <ReferenceProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>263973</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>320056</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>934789</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </ReferenceProducts>
            <RelatedIntProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <RelationId>116881</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>208076</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>116886</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </RelatedIntProducts>
            <S1>1001</S1>
            <S2>1986</S2>
        </Standard>
        <Standard>
            <ProductID>200058</ProductID>
            <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
            <SNumber>1002</SNumber>
            <DraftProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>1500167</ProductID>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </DraftProducts>
            <ReferenceProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>263974</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>320052</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>934754</RelationId>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </ReferenceProducts>
            <RelatedIntProducts>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                    <RelationId>116837</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
                </RelatedProduct>
                <RelatedProduct>
                    <ProductID>208074</ProductID>
                    <RelationId>116843</RelationId>
                    <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                    <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                </RelatedProduct>
            </RelatedIntProducts>
            <S1>1005</S1>
            <S2>1983</S2>
        </Standard>
    </Standards>
```

into the following output format.

```
<Standards xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice">
    <Product>
        <ProductID>200057</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1001</SNumber>
        <RelatedProducts>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>1500163</ProductID>
                <RelationType>DraftProducts</RelationType>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>263973</ProductID>
                <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>320056</ProductID>
                <RelationId>934789</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <RelationId>116881</RelationId>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>208076</ProductID>
                <RelationId>116886</RelationId>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
        </RelatedProducts>
        <S1>1001</S1>
        <S2>1986</S2>
    </Product>
    <Product>
        <ProductID>200058</ProductID>
        <Prefix>ISO</Prefix>
        <SNumber>1002</SNumber>
        <RelatedProducts>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>1500167</ProductID>
                <RelationType>DraftProducts</RelationType>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>263974</ProductID>
                <RelationId>708519</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>320052</ProductID>
                <RelationId>934754</RelationId>
                <RelationType>ReferenceProducts</RelationType>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
                <RelationId>116837</RelationId>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <Designation>NEN ISO 1001</Designation>
            </RelatedProduct>
            <RelatedProduct>
                <ProductID>208074</ProductID>
                <RelationId>116843</RelationId>
                <RelationType>RelatedIntProducts</RelationType>
                <Relationship>Identical</Relationship>
                <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
            </RelatedProduct>
        </RelatedProducts>
        <S1>1005</S1>
        <S2>1983</S2>
    </Product>
</Standards>
```

With the help of others I could write the following xslt to do this transformation.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice" xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice"
    exclude-result-prefixes="x" version="1.0">

    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" />

    <!-- Identity Transform -->
    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" />
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="x:Standard">
        <Product>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductID" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Prefix" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:SNumber" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Year" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Designation" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Publisher" />
            <RelatedProducts>
                <xsl:apply-templates select=".//x:RelatedProduct" />
            </RelatedProducts>
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductICSCodes" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductDescriptions" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:IndustryCodes" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductAttributes" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductReconfirmationNotices" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Type" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:SaleItems" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Committee" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:CommentClosesDate" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Note" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:InternalNote" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:DummyProductLink" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:Status" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:State" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:UpdateNote" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ThumbnailPath" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:SortOrder" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:EntryDate" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:ExpiryDate" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:SupersededDate" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:UpdateDate" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:WithdrawnDate" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:PluginName" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S1" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S2" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S3" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S4" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S5" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S6" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S7" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S8" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S9" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:S10" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:HasLexConnect" />
            <xsl:copy-of select="x:HasCodeConnect" />
        </Product>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="x:RelatedProduct">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|*[not(name()='RelationId')]" />
            <RelationType>
                <xsl:value-of select="name(..)" />
            </RelationType>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Now I need to rename the root element as **Products** instead of **Standards** and eliminate all the **nil** values from the output. The nil values have the following format.

```
 <Designation xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <Abstract xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <History xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
        <TOC xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/>
```

I added the following xslt segment which renamed the root element as **Products**.

```
<xsl:template match="x:Standards">
    <Products namespace="{namespace-uri()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select=".//x:Standard" />
    </Products>
</xsl:template>
```

Is that correct? How can I change the above xslt to eliminate all the **nil** values from the output. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: _"Is that correct"_ -- Did it produce the output you were expecting?  It is not necessary for you to check out every change by asking a question here.  TRY IT!  As to eliminating values with `xsi:nil="true"`, you know how to write a matching template for that, just make the template empty.

Comment: I got the expected output. But I could not eliminate that nil values yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the namesace declaration for xsi to your stylesheet

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

Add a template to ignore `xsi:nil`

```
<xsl:template match="@xsi:nil"/>
```

And change your `xsl:copy-of` to  `xsl:apply-templates`.
For example change:

```
<xsl:copy-of select="x:ProductID" />
```

to:

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="x:ProductID" />
```

**Update:**
To ignore all nodes with nil attribute try:

```
<xsl:template match="*[@xsi:nil]"/>
```

Comment: I tried the suggested approach, but now i am getting empty xml tags as follows. <Designation /> for nil elements. Requirement is to eliminate all the nil nodes.

Comment: Yes - I thought  this was hat you are expecting. But sounds as you like to ignore element with nil not onyl the nil attribute

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind corporation.That worked. I am in a bit tight schedule, not having enough time to experiment. Thanks again. :)